# PHP REGEX: Remove/replace quotes within an XML attribute

Tags: php, regex

Please consider the following line from an XML file (generated from a third-party source):

```
<record ObTime="2017-05-10T23:30" data_value="Ocean Park "The Sea WX"  WA US" />
```

As you can see, the attribute `data_value` has quoted string inside the value, which causes XML validators to giggle and explode.

Any given XML file could have thousands of lines.  Is there a way to apply REGEX to a whole file?  And, what would the REGEX be to replace quotes with something more benign?

Answer (score 2):

There might be other, and better, solutions, but this is how I made it works:

- Using [**`preg_match_all`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) with certain regex to capture *all* matches,  and store them in an array **`$matches[0]`**.
- [The regex](https://regex101.com/r/uhnJH6/2/): **`(?<=data_value=").*(?=" \/>)`** will capture everything between `data_value="` and `" />)`, by making use of *positive* [lookbehind and lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), precisely match the *values* of each of the **`data_value`** attributes.
- Loop through items in **`$matches[0]`** and we do the following:

  1. Replace every double qoutes string **`"`** with **`%`** [could be any other string, even blank, that doesn't cause further problems] in every single match, and store it in a temporary variable **`$str`**.
  2. Then replace the value of each match in the whole data string with the value of the modified version of the match, the **`$str`** string.

**PHP code:** 
*<sub>remember that because the data is xml tags, you need to use "view source" in order to see the output, alternatively, you can use `var_dump` instead of `echo`</sub>*

```php
<?php
$data = '<record ObTime="2017-05-10T23:30" data_value="Ocean Park "The Sea WX"  WA US" />
<record ObTime="2017-11-10T23:30" data_value="Some Other "Demo Text"  In Here" />';

$data_valueVal = preg_match_all('#(?<=data_value=").*(?=" \/>)#i', $data, $matches);

foreach($matches[0] as $match) {
    $str = str_replace('"', "%", $match);
    $data = str_replace($match, $str, $data);
}
echo $data;
?>
```

---

**Output:**

> `<record ObTime="2017-05-10T23:30" data_value="Ocean Park %The Sea WX%  WA US" />`
>   `<record ObTime="2017-11-10T23:30" data_value="Some Other %Demo Text%  In Here" />`

Comment: thank you very much.  I'll look at applying this to each file before parsing.

Comment: You're welcome and I'm glad it helped.. enjoy coding!

Comment: for the new xml data sample, use this regex **`(?<=data_value=")[^=]+(?=" (?:\w+=)?)`**  [**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/uhnJH6/3) instead of the one in my answer, it can capture both `data_value` attributes

Comment: And if you only want to capture the second `data_value` , use **`(?<=data_value=")[^=]+(?=" \/>)`** instead, [**regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/uhnJH6/4)

Answer (score 1):

Using Regex below, you are able to match those double quotes separately for further modifications:

```
(?:="|"\s+(?:\w+="|\/>))(*SKIP)(?!)|"
```

By using [`(*SKIP)(?!)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex) you force engine to jump over first side of alternation after each successful match.

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/toFV9f/1)

PHP code (removing quotes):

```
echo preg_replace('~(?:="|"\s+(?:\w+="|\/>))(*SKIP)(?!)|"~', '', $xml);
```

Comment: That's a nice one, never heard of this `(*SKIP)(?!)`  before, Up Voted!

Comment: Wow... SKIP is cool.  I'm brand new to REGEX so everything is like magic to me...  but this is the first I've seen of SKIP. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @revo, It looks like the quote in the <xml> opening tag is caught as well.  This demo has more verbose data to look at.

https://regex101.com/r/toFV9f/4

Comment: You may want to change `\/>` part in regex to `[\/?]>`.

Comment: this why you should always provide a [**MCVE**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the data sample in the question ***differs*** than the data you have put in the regex101 example.. that changes the rules whether in revo's or my answers.

Comment: It doesn't work if there is no ending space like this `<record ObTime="2017-05-10T23:30" data_value="Ocean Park "The Sea WX"  WA US"/>`

Comment: @TomSawyer Change `\s+` to `\s*`.

Comment: Thank you, i want to convert it to go but it's the pain since `(*SKIP)` isn't available :(